How to find the coordinates in a text?
This is my some of text:
PalHebron Governorate, Palestine31°31′27″N 35°6′32″E / 31.52417°N 35.10889°E /  / 31.52417; 35.10889 (Hebron/Al-Khalil Old Town)
Cultural:(ii), (iv), (vi)
20.6 (51)
2017
2017–

[51]

OdesaOdesa, Ukraine46°29′11.22″N 30°44′29.81″E / 46.4864500°N 30.7416139°E / 4  46.4864500; 30.7416139 (Historic Centre of Odesa)
Cultural:(ii), (iv)
—
2023
2023–
Russo-Ukrainian War
[52][53]

And I want to extract for example: 46.4864500°N 30.7416139°E and 1.52417°N 35.10889°E
import re

text = 'UzbQashqadaryo Region, Uzbekistan39°3′0″N 66°50′0″E / 39.05000°N 66.83333°E /    39.05000; 66.83333 (Historic Centre of Shakhrisyabz)
Cultural:(iii), (iv)
240 (590)
2000
2016–
Destruction of buildings in its medieval neighbourhoods and continuing urban development.
[55][56]

AutVienna,  Austria48°12′N 16°22′E / 48.200°N 16.367°E / 48.200; 16.367 (Vien   nna)
Cultural:(ii), (iv), (vi)
371 (920)
2001
2017–
New high-rise projects
[57]

YemAl Hudaydah, Yemen14°12′N 43°19′E / 14.200°N 43.317°E / 14.200; 43.317 (Hi   istoric Town of Zabīd)
Cultural:(ii), (iv), (vi)'

# Definir el patrón de expresión regular para encontrar texto entre "//"
pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+/{1}\s{1}")

# Encontrar todas las coincidencias del patrón en el texto del párrafo
matches = pattern.findall(text)

# Imprimir las coincidencias encontradas
print(matches)
                     

I tried with this code, get the coordinates but doesn't nothing, what can I do?

what's your desired output?

Have list with coordinates, for example: ['9.00000°S 37.40000°E',  '34.200°N 43.867°E',  '16.77333°N 2.99944°W', 'other coordinates']

ok thats how those cruise missiles are programmed actually

I believe this is what you are looking for :
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+°[NS]\s\d+\.\d+°[EW]")

output:
['39.05000°N 66.83333°E', '48.200°N 16.367°E', '14.200°N 43.317°E']


Excuse me, if I want get from ' AutVienna,  Austria48°12′N 16°22′E / 48.200°N 16.367°E / 48.200; 16.367 (Vienna)', this ''14.200; 43.317', what can I do? Thank for your help.

@MidasEstanislao not sure what you want to extract? the '14.200; 43.317 doesn't exists in the text you are mentioning
